# PHP OOP PDO Error Display

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I am building an OOP/PDO login system for my website but, I don't know how I can correctly display error messages within my login class when the user login attempt fails. Also, I would like to know if my OOP approach is right. This is my first project working with OOP and PDO. If you have any suggestions for my code I would like to hear them.

login.class.php

```
<?php
    class Login {
        private $dbConnection;
        private $studentNumber;
        private $studentClass;
        private $errorMessage = false;

        public function __construct($dbConnection) {
            $this->dbConnection = $dbConnection->dbConnection;
        }

        public function showErrorMessage() {
            return $this->errorMessage;
        }

        public function studentLogin($studentNumber, $studentClass) {
            $this->studentNumber = $studentNumber;
            $this->studentClass = $studentClass;

            $selectStudent = $this->dbConnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_students WHERE studentNumber = :studentNumber AND studentClass = :studentClass LIMIT 1");
            $selectStudent->bindParam(':studentNumber', $this->studentNumber);
            $selectStudent->bindParam(':studentClass', $this->studentClass);
            $selectStudent->execute();

            $selectStudentCheck = $selectStudent->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if(!empty($selectStudentCheck)) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                $this->errorMessage = "Studentnumber or class is not correct";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

dbconnection.class.php

```
<?php
    class DatabaseConnection {
        private $DatabaseHost = "localhost";
        private $DatabaseName = "plansysteem_keuzetrainingen";
        private $userName = "root";
        private $passWord = "root";
        public $dbConnection;

        public function __construct() {
            $this->databaseConnect();
        }

        public function databaseConnect() {
            try{
                $this->dbConnection = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->DatabaseHost;dbname=$this->DatabaseName", $this->userName, $this->passWord);
                $this->dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            }
            catch(PDOException $e){
                print("Sorry er kan geen verbinding worden gemaakt met de database");
                file_put_contents("../errors/database.connection.errors.txt", $e->getMessage().PHP_EOL,FILE_APPEND);
                die();
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

login form

```
<?php
    session_start();

    include ("../classes/dbconnection.class.php");
    include ("../classes/login.class.php");

    if(isset($_POST["submitLogin"])) {
        $studentNumber = $_POST["studentNumber"];
        $studentClass = $_POST["studentClass"];

        $dbConnection = new DatabaseConnection();
        $login = new Login($dbConnection);
        if($login->studentLogin($studentNumber, $studentClass)) {
            echo "Succes";
        }
        else {
             echo "Student not found!";
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="nl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="Communication Centre" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Login Plansysteem Keuzetrainingen</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../img/favicon.png" sizes="16x16 32x32" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/foundation.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Advent+Pro" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 medium-8 medium-offset-2 large-6 large-offset-3 columns">
                <h1 class="mainTitle">inloggen</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form method="post">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="small-12 medium-8 medium-offset-2 large-6 large-offset-3 columns">
                    <small class="error"></small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="small-12 medium-8 medium-offset-2 large-6 large-offset-3 columns">
                    <div class="row collapse">
                        <div class="small-2 medium-1 large-1 columns">
                            <span class="prefix">
                                <img src="../img/cursor_icon.png" alt="Cursor Icon" />
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="small-10 medium-11 large-11 columns">
                            <input type="text" name="studentNumber" placeholder="Studentnummer" class="placeholderBlack" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="small-12 medium-8 medium-offset-2 large-6 large-offset-3 columns">
                    <div class="row collapse">
                        <div class="small-2 medium-1 large-1 columns">
                            <span class="prefix">
                                <img src="../img/person_icon.png" alt="Person Icon" />
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="small-10 medium-11 large-11 columns">
                            <select name="studentClass">
                                <option value="">Selecteer Klas</option>
                                <option value="1DVTM-REG-01.P1">1DVTM-REG-01.P1</option>
                                <option value="1DVTM-REG-02.P1">1DVTM-REG-02.P1</option>
                                <option value="1DVTM-REG-03.P1">1DVTM-REG-03.P1</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="small-12 medium-8 medium-offset-2 large-6 large-offset-3 columns">
                    <input type="submit" name="submitLogin" value="Login" class="button expand buttonBlack" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/foundation.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).foundation();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks quite a bit like the login system that I have built for my projects, as far as returning error messages, you can assign the error to a variable and use it with return to pass it along. Another thing that may be easier to do is to use an ajax call for the login instead of having the php directly on the page. This would also allow for you to dynamically assign error/success messages.

But as far as returning the error messages you could change the catch to something like this

```
        $status = [];
        if(!empty($selectStudentCheck)) {
            status['status'] = true;
            return status;
        }
        else {
            $status['status'] = false;
            $status['msg'] = "Studentnumber or class is not correct";
            return $status;
        }
```

this would also remove the need for the `showErrorMessage()` function. You would then to need to just check `['status']` and then display `['msg']` if you want to display the error. The above would also work well with an ajax call.

One other thing that I noticed that you may want to do is to move your database info into a separate file to be included so that you can set permission on  it so that the info is more secure. Something I have done with mine is the following

db_info.inc

```
<?php
# Defining Database Values to avoid hardcoding in each file.
define ('DB_USER', 'user');
define ('DB_PASS', 'supersecret password');
define ('DB_HOST_WRITE', 'host1'); # Master DB
define ('DB_HOST_READ', 'host2'); # Slave DB
define ('DB_ONE', 'database1');
define ('DB_TWO', 'database2');
```

Then just include the the file and assign them to the variables you need and inset them where they need to be. such as below.

```
class User {

# Set class wide variables
private $db;
public $dbuser = DB_USER;
public $dbhost = DB_HOST_WRITE;
public $dbname = DB_ONE;
public $dbpass = DB_PASS;
```

Also you can construct the actual database connection inside the construct. of the actual login class so that you don't have to pass it into the login functions. This can also allow you to more easily assign database rights to users for special functions.

```
public function __construct() {
    try {
        $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->dbhost . ";dbname=" . $this->dbname, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
        $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        file_put_contents($this->pdolog, $ex->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

==========

For the ajax call the blow is snippets from my own implementatation

the login form

```
<form id="formLogin">
    <input class="form-control center-block text-center" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" required>
    <input class="form-control center-block text-center" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" required>
    <input type="button" value="Login" id="login" class="btn btn-block btn-primary center-block" onclick="userlogin(event, '#formLogin')">
</form>
```

The `onlick` option is the magic part. It calls the following jquery script.

```
function userlogin(event, loginform) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $('#login').fadeOut();

  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/inc/login.php',
        data: $(loginform).serializeArray(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          if (data.status == 'error') {
            alert(data.statusmsg);
            $('#login').fadeIn();
          }
          if (data.status == 'success') {
            window.location = '/account/';
          }
        },
        error: LogonError
  });
}
function LogonError() {
   alert('Error: The system could not log you in.' +
       '\n\nIf you believe this is an error please email the' +
       '\nAdministrator at admin@blacklistlogistics.com');
}
```

This takes the values from the form with jquery doing all the extra magix so I dont have to and passes it to the php page login.php

login.php

```
$user = @$_POST['username'];
$pass = @$_POST['password'];

$response = array();

if($user == null) {
    $errors = 1;
    $response['statusmsg'] .= "Please enter your username.\n";
}
if($pass == null) {
    $errors = 1;
    $response['statusmsg'] .= "Please enter your password.\n";
}
if($errors === 1) {
    $response['status'] = 'error';
    echo json_encode($response);
    return;
} else {
    $login = new User;
    $loginstatus = $login->login($user, $pass);

    if($loginstatus === 0) {
        $response['status'] = 'error';
        $response['statusmsg'] = "The system was unable to log you in. Please try again later.\nIf this error presists please inform the site administrator.";
        echo json_encode($response);
        return;
    }
    if($loginstatus === 2) {
        $response['status'] = 'error';
        $response['statusmsg'] = "There was an error. Please try again later.\nIf this error presists please inform the site administrator.";
        echo json_encode($response);
        return;
    }
    if($loginstatus === 1) {
        $response['status'] = 'success';
        echo json_encode($response);
        return;
    }
}
```

This grabs the info that jquery passed us out of the post and then passes it to the login function and then checks the return values and passes the info needed back to jquery to display errors etc.

the login function

```
public function login($username, $password) {
        # Set login time
        $logintime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $ip = filter_var($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP);

        # setting db connection inside try for exception handling
        try {
            $conn = $this->db;

            $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM Members WHERE UserName = :username');
            $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username));
            $results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $stmt = NULL;
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            $conn = NULL;
            file_put_contents($this->pdolog, $ex->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
            return 2;
        }

        if ($results === FALSE || $results['AccountActive'] === 0) {
            $conn = NULL;
            return 0;
        } else {
            if (password_verify($password, $results['UserPass'])) {
                try {
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE Members SET LastDate = :lastdate, LastIP = :lastip, FailCount = :failcount WHERE MemberID = :memberid');
                    $stmt->execute(array(':lastdate' => $logintime, ':lastip' => $ip, ':failcount' => 0, ':memberid' => $results['MemberID']));
                } catch (PDOException $ex) {
                    $conn = NULL;
                    file_put_contents($this->pdolog, $ex->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
                    return 2;
                }

                $conn = NULL;
                $_SESSION['login'] = 1;
                $_SESSION['MemberID'] = $results['MemberID'];
                $_SESSION['UserName'] = $results['UserName'];
                return 1;

            } else {
                $conn = NULL;
                return 0;
            }

        }

    }
```

after the function has run and data has been passed back to the jquery call, jquery then process the data in the `success` or `error` portions.

Hope this helps as well, also sorry for the long copy/paste code. also I kept the majority of the extra peices of my code intact just incase you would like to pull ideas from it.

Comment: Thanks Gluzzer for your fast reply to my question! Can you tell me how I can combine an AJAX call with PHP login class? This seems a little bit difficult to me.